# How to sort in a WPF ListBox?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, sorting, event-handling

The C# 4.0 WPF application, see the code below, shows on startup:

[image: Initial order of in <code>ListBox</code>]

abd after clicking the **Sort** button with `btnSort_Click()` click event handler:

[image: ListBox After Sorting]

How can I sort in order aaa, bbb, ccc?

C# code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  listBox1.Items.Add("ccc");
  listBox1.Items.Add("aaa");
  listBox1.Items.Add("bbb");
}
private void btnSort_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  listBox1.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(
  new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Content",
       System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
}
private void listBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  listBox1.Items.RemoveAt
     (listBox1.Items.IndexOf(listBox1.SelectedItem));
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8,43,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" MouseDoubleClick="listBox1_MouseDoubleClick" />
        <Button Content="Sort" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="140,94,0,0" Name="btnSort" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnSort_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Update:**
Well, I simply followed the article ["Sorting a WPF ListBox Items"](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/resources/855/sorting-a-wpf-listbox-items.aspx)

So, what is the order by which I am sorting by a property "Content" and where is that property "Content", I wonder (tried to change it to arbitrary "fff" instead of "Content" having gotten the same, as in 2nd screenshot, results?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since you're sorting a list of strings, don't indicate a property name (first parameter of SortDescription):

```
listBox1.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(
            new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("",
            System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're asking now... Did changing the code to my suggestion fix this issue?

Comment: It did work. I'd like to understand what is the 1st argument of `SortDescription()` method for and why it doesn't give an error after providing arbitrary `propertyName` + why is the order changes at all (and according to which sorting rules)?

Comment: Well, it does give an error. If you use an arbitrary propertyname such as `fff` and open your `output window` in Visual Studio, you'll see a binding error such as: `System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'fff' property not found on 'object' ''String' (HashCode=536926232)'.`

Comment: Thanks. I failed to notice that error! But if it gives an error why the order of items is changed, I assume being re-sorted?

Answer (score 7):

```
YOULISTBOX.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear(); 
YOULISTBOX.Items.SortDescriptions.Add( new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("NAME", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

to ensure it update every time

Answer (score 5):

It's easy to sort a wpf combobox or listbox - but remember to include Imports `System.ComponentModel`.

To sort in alphabetical order,  simply

```
MylistBox.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(
    New SortDescription("", ListSortDirection.Ascending))
```

or

```
MyComboBox.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(
    New SortDescription("", ListSortDirection.Ascending))
```

Answer (score 3):

Additional info:

The item that you sort with may be any `DependencyProperty`.  So lets say that you have an `ObservableCollection` of a custom class that is bound to the `ItemsSource` of the ListBox control.  The custom class can have any number of dependency properties, and you can use those for the sort(s).  You just put the name of the dependency property (as a `string`) in the new `SortDescription` argument.

Adding multiple `SortDescription`s to the control will do a multi-variable sort.

The dependency properties may represent any type of variable and not just strings.  I have an example where I am sorting first by a `bool`, then by an `int`, and finally by `DateTime`.