# Sort Alphabetic ObservableCollection binded to ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, observablecollection

I wrote a little Function for scanning Files with Virus Total using the API. Its working great but the Scan Result is not Sorted Alphabetic.

Here is my Code:

```
public void init(FileReport _scanResult) {

        try {

            if (_scanResult.ResponseCode == ReportResponseCode.Present) {
                foreach (ScanEngine scan in _scanResult.Scans) {
                    if (scan.Detected == true) {
                        howMany++;
                        _scanResultItems.Add(new ScanResultItems {
                            AvName = scan.Name,
                            AvResult = new Uri("/Images/inWatch.avNOT.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                            AvStatus = "BEDROHUNG!"
                        });
                        Width = 390;
                    }
                    else {
                        _scanResultItems.Add(new ScanResultItems {
                            AvName = scan.Name,
                            AvResult = new Uri("/Images/inWatch.avOK.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute),
                            AvStatus = "OK"
                        });
                    }
                }

                lstScanResults.ItemsSource = _scanResultItems.OrderBy(item => item.AvName).ToList();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            GeneralSettings.LogException(ex);
        }
```

Thanks for your Answers!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1280768/440030 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/15600179/440030

Comment: thanks for the Answer but none of them seems to Work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could order items inside your result set by using System.Linq; OrderBy() method, like this:

```
_scanResultItems = _scanResultItems.OrderBy(item => item.Name).ToList();
```