# C# WPF - Show items sorted in ListBox after adding new item in DataView

Tags: c#, wpf, dataview

How can I sort DataView when I add new item?
I have UserControl that contains ListBox control with ItemsSource set to DataView. When I add new item into DataView item is always shown as last in ListBox.
What's the best way to sort DataView and show new item in ListBox as sorted?

```
DataView ListBoxItems = new DataView();

private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = ..."SELECT * FROM table" //populated from database

    ListBoxItems = dt.DefaultView;

    ListBoxItems.Sort = "Col1 DESC, Col2 ASC";

    ListBox.ItemsSource = ListBoxItems;
}

//Adding new item into DataView
DataRowView row = ListBoxItems.AddNew();
row["Col1"] = value1;
row["Col2"] = value2;
ListBoxItems.EndInit();                   
ListBox.SelectedItem = row;
ListBox.ScrollIntoView(row);
```

EDIT:
I tried solution from link provided by Max Play but without success.
Updated code for adding new item:

```
//Adding new item into DataView
DataRowView row = ListBoxItems.AddNew();
row["Col1"] = value1;
row["Col2"] = value2;
ListBoxItems.EndInit();

ListBox.Items.SortDescriptions.Clear();
ListBox.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Col1", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending));
ListBox.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new System.ComponentModel.SortDescription("Col2", System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending));
                   
ListBox.SelectedItem = row;
ListBox.ScrollIntoView(row);
```

New item is always shown last in ListBox instead first (based on sorting options).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort in a WPF ListBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15600099/how-to-sort-in-a-wpf-listbox)

Comment: Why do you have two sorts, one descending, then immediately followed by ascending?  Perhaps you meant to combine those two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution, now works as expected.

```
DataView ListBoxItems = new DataView();

private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = ..."SELECT * FROM table" //populated from database

    ListBoxItems = dt.DefaultView;

    ListBoxItems.Sort = "Col1 DESC, Col2 ASC";

    ListBox.ItemsSource = ListBoxItems;
}

//Adding new item
BindingListCollectionView cv = (BindingListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ListBox.ItemsSource);
DataRowView row = (DataRowView) cv.AddNew();
row["Col1"] = value1;
row["Col2"] = value2;
cv.CommitNew();              
cv.SortDescriptions.Clear();
cv.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Col1", ListSortDirection.Descending));
cv.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Col2", ListSortDirection.Ascending));                 
ListBox.SelectedItem = row;
ListBox.ScrollIntoView(row);
```